# APIC and LAPIC work with dual E5410 but not with dual E5420

Tags: 13.04, apic

I have a iDataPlex system with 2 dx340 system modules. One has dual Xeon E5410 processors and the other board has dual E5420 processors. I can install ESXi and Ubuntu on the board with the E5410 processors without issue but neither will install on the board with the E5420 processors. I have to specify noapic and nolapic to install and run Ubuntu and have not found an equivelent from ESXi 5.1 to try that. There is no difference in the system boards and I have even swapped the processors between the boards and the problem follows the E5420 processors. Trying to install ESXi 4.0 IBM distribution got me some debug output after what I assume was a kernel panic. It is essentially saying the apicID of two of the cores is set to 0x00. If I remove one processor this issue goes away. Is this more a motherboard/bios issue? If I use noapic/nolapic do I limit myself to using a single core of the 8 core system?

Comment: This could very well be a BIOS issue. See http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5086609#DOCPRODUCTS